# Pass RecyclerView press to super view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin

I have a `RecyclerView` (which scrolls vertically) whose `ViewHolder`s contain `RecyclerView`s that scroll horizontally. When you tap on an item in horizontal (nested) `RecyclerView`s, I want the entire row to have the ripple effect.

To do this, I've been trying to override the touch events and get them to get passed up the view stack (by returning `false` in touch event handlers). This works on views other than `RecyclerView`s, but it isn't having the desired effect for `RecyclerView`s.

How do I correctly pass the tap event on a `RecyclerView` up to the enclosing view?

Comment: If you want one click event to go to an entire row of click events (or something else) then I feel that's not the way to do it. Instead you can just use the click event of the view clicked to go to a method that does what you decide to the other views. In this case, you create an inner class and cache all the views then you can manipulate any view(s) you wish however you desire as is done here https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling .Of course if you want the click event to pass & just go up one then it sounds like its not the same view so I don't see how.

Comment: @CmosBattery Because I'm trying to get the ripple effect, and not just the fact that a subview was clicked, I can't use the method you provided :/ Thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

Haven't found a way to pass the click event up to a recycler view's parent view, but the important thing was getting the ripple effect to happen – which I *was* able to do. So when a view holder's `itemView` get's tapped, I do this:

```
val background = itemView.background
if (background is RippleDrawable) {
    background.setState(intArrayOf(android.R.attr.state_pressed, android.R.attr.state_enabled))
}
```

Which manually triggers the ripple effect.